# Sprite Animations In the Phaserjs Duration error

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I Have a phaser animation from the default phaser make your first game tutorial on the website

```js
this.load.spritesheet(
      "Player",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(10).png?v=1675733526924",
      { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 24 }
    );
```

The Animations

```js
this.anims.create({
      key: "left",
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player", { start: 0, end: 3 }),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: -1,
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: "turn",
      frames: [{ key: "player", frame: 4 }],
      frameRate: 20,
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: "right",
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player", { start: 5, end: 8 }),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: -1,
    });
```

I get the Error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration')

when ever i use the animations in update
what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the two different key's for the sprite.

On `this.load.spritesheet("Player",...` you are using '**P**layer' (upper case **P**) and on `this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player",...` you are using '**p**layer' (lower case **p**).
And since in Phaser the key-names are case sensitive it is not found, and this error is occurs.

Just make all keys the same *(I recommend lowercase 'player', I personally always use lower case and dash-case, to prevent such typos/errors)*, and it should work.

Comment: My case was similar but not exactly the same. Sprite image path had a typo, and this was causing this error.